# Javascript countdown time incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I have an issue with a Jquery countdown timer. The script counts down to the same time every day.
The countdown time is incorrect, it is one hour off. Any ideas how to fix this? It's hosted at JSFiddle.

```js
(function($){
  var date    = new Date(),
      month   = date.getMonth();
      day     = date.getDate(),
      weekDay = date.getDay(),
      hours   = {
        start: new Date(date.getFullYear(), month, day),
        end: new Date(date.getFullYear(), month, day)
      };
  
  // weekDay var [0 = sun, 1 = mon, 2 = tues ... 5 = fri 6 = sat]
  
  // If it's Monday - Friday
  if(weekDay >= 1 && weekDay <= 5){

    // Start at 7am, end at 8pm
    hours.start.setHours(7);
    hours.end.setHours(22);

  // If it's Saturday
  } else if(weekDay == 6){

    // Start at 8am, end at 8pm
    hours.start.setHours(8);
    hours.end.setHours(20);

  // If it's Sunday
  } else {

    // Start at 9am, end at 6pm
    hours.start.setHours(9);
    hours.end.setHours(18);
  }

  function countDown(){
    var date         = new Date(),
        countHours   = ('0' + (hours.end.getHours() - date.getHours())).substr(-2),
        countMinutes = ('0' + (59 - date.getMinutes())).substr(-2),
        countSeconds = ('0' + (59 - date.getSeconds())).substr(-2);

    // If it's currently not within the hours, don't show the countdown
    if(date.getHours() < hours.start.getHours() || date.getHours() > hours.end.getHours()){
      $('.countdown').hide();
    } else if($('.countdown').not(':visible')){
      $('.countdown').show();
    }

    $('.countdown .hours').text(countHours);
    $('.countdown .minutes').text(countMinutes);
    $('.countdown .seconds').html(countSeconds);

  }

  $(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
      countDown();
    }, 1000);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown">
<span class="hours"></span>H <span class="minutes"></span>M <span class="seconds"></span>S
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisoliver1990/s1nzydfj/36/

Comment: When calculating the hours, you are not taking into account the *minutes*. Same thing happens with minutes and seconds.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't correctly calculating the hours and minutes. Assuming you want to finish the countdown at 22:00 and it's currently 10:30, then this is 11 hours and 30 minutes.

However, your calculation just does `hours.end.getHours() - date.getHours()` which, using the values above, yields `22 - 10`. This is `12`, not `11`, because the code doesn't take into account the half an hour that already passed.

The same problem appears with the minutes but it's less apparent. Still, the minutes display is 1 off because it doesn't take into account the seconds that have already passed.

Instead, you should take a different approach and get the total difference *in seconds*, then calculate the hours, minutes, and seconds this represents:

```js
var end = new Date('2020-01-10T22:00:00');

//let's fake it to 10:30:42
var current = new Date('2020-01-10T10:30:42');

//getTime returns milliseconds, divide by 1000 to get seconds
var differenceInSeconds = Math.floor((end.getTime() - current.getTime()) / 1000);

//for convenience
var secondsInHour = 60 * 60;
var secondsInMinute = 60;


var hours = Math.floor(differenceInSeconds / secondsInHour);

//take the hours out of the difference
differenceInSeconds -= hours * secondsInHour;

var minutes = Math.floor(differenceInSeconds / secondsInMinute);

//take the minutes out of the difference
differenceInSeconds -= minutes * secondsInMinute;

//the rest is just the seconds left
var seconds = differenceInSeconds;

console.log(hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Adding this time calculation to your code correctly calculates the remaining time:

```js
(function($){
  var date    = new Date(),
      month   = date.getMonth();
      day     = date.getDate(),
      weekDay = date.getDay(),
      hours   = {
        start: new Date(date.getFullYear(), month, day),
        end: new Date(date.getFullYear(), month, day)
      };
  
  // weekDay var [0 = sun, 1 = mon, 2 = tues ... 5 = fri 6 = sat]
  
  // If it's Monday - Friday
  if(weekDay >= 1 && weekDay <= 5){

    // Start at 7am, end at 8pm
    hours.start.setHours(7);
    hours.end.setHours(22);

  // If it's Saturday
  } else if(weekDay == 6){

    // Start at 8am, end at 8pm
    hours.start.setHours(8);
    hours.end.setHours(20);

  // If it's Sunday
  } else {

    // Start at 9am, end at 6pm
    hours.start.setHours(9);
    hours.end.setHours(18);
  }
  
  function formatNumber(num) {
    return ('0' + num).substr(-2);
  }
  
  function countDown(){
    var date         = new Date();
    
    var end = new Date('2020-01-10T22:00:00'),
        differenceInSeconds = Math.floor((hours.end.getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000);

    //for convenience
    var secondsInHour = 60 * 60;
    var secondsInMinute = 60;

    var countHours = formatNumber(Math.floor(differenceInSeconds / secondsInHour));

    differenceInSeconds -= countHours * secondsInHour;

    var countMinutes = formatNumber(Math.floor(differenceInSeconds / secondsInMinute));

    differenceInSeconds -= countMinutes * secondsInMinute;
    
    var countSeconds = formatNumber(differenceInSeconds);

    // If it's currently not within the hours, don't show the countdown
    if(date.getHours() < hours.start.getHours() || date.getHours() > hours.end.getHours()){
      $('.countdown').hide();
    } else if($('.countdown').not(':visible')){
      $('.countdown').show();
    }

    $('.countdown .hours').text(countHours);
    $('.countdown .minutes').text(countMinutes);
    $('.countdown .seconds').html(countSeconds);

  }

  $(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
      countDown();
    }, 1000);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown">
<span class="hours"></span>H <span class="minutes"></span>M <span class="seconds"></span>S
</div>
```

(I also introduced a helper function `formatNumber` to encapsulate the logic for displaying the zero in front of a number or not)

Answer (score -1):

`setHours` hoursValue parameter is 0 based, so when you want it to be 8PM, you set it to 19 (not 20). Check - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours

`

```js
    (function($){
      var date    = new Date(),
          month   = date.getMonth();
          day     = date.getDate(),
          weekDay = date.getDay(),
          hours   = {
            start: new Date(date.getFullYear(), month, day),
            end: new Date(date.getFullYear(), month, day)
          };
      
      // weekDay var [0 = sun, 1 = mon, 2 = tues ... 5 = fri 6 = sat]
      
      // If it's Monday - Friday
      if(weekDay >= 1 && weekDay <= 5){

        // Start at 7am, end at 8pm
        hours.start.setHours(7);
        hours.end.setHours(19);

      // If it's Saturday
      } else if(weekDay == 6){

        // Start at 8am, end at 8pm
        hours.start.setHours(8);
        hours.end.setHours(20);

      // If it's Sunday
      } else {

        // Start at 9am, end at 6pm
        hours.start.setHours(9);
        hours.end.setHours(18);
      }

      function countDown(){
        var date         = new Date(),
            countHours   = ('0' + (hours.end.getHours() - date.getHours())).substr(-2),
            countMinutes = ('0' + (59 - date.getMinutes())).substr(-2),
            countSeconds = ('0' + (59 - date.getSeconds())).substr(-2);

        // If it's currently not within the hours, don't show the countdown
        if(date.getHours() < hours.start.getHours() || date.getHours() > hours.end.getHours()){
          $('.countdown').hide();
        } else if($('.countdown').not(':visible')){
          $('.countdown').show();
        }

        $('.countdown .hours').text(countHours);
        $('.countdown .minutes').text(countMinutes);
        $('.countdown .seconds').html(countSeconds);

      }

      $(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
          countDown();
        }, 1000);
      });
    })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown">
    <span class="hours"></span>H <span class="minutes"></span>M <span class="seconds"></span>S
    </div>
```

Comment: "*`setHours` hoursValue parameter is 0 based, so when you want it to be 8PM, you set it to 19 (not 20)*" this is completely wrong. The start of the day is 00:00 and 8 PM is 20:00. 8PM is *exactly* 20 hours after the start of the day: 0 to 12 o'clock is 12 hours and when you add another 8 you get 20.

Comment: This is mentioned in MDN. Please refer the link I shared. From MDN - 
`hoursValue
Ideally, an integer between 0 and 23, representing the hour. If a value greater than 23 is provided, the datetime will be incremented by the extra hours.`

Comment: Sure, and *as with every other 24-hour clock* - `0` is midnight, `1` = 1AM, `2` = 2AM, `3` = 3AM, etc., until `12` which is 12PM, then you have `13` = 1PM, `14` = 2PM, `15` = 3PM, `16` = 4PM, `17` = 5 PM, `18` = 6PM, `19` = 7PM, `20` = 8PM, `21` = 9PM, `22` = 10PM, `23` = 11PM and it wraps around to `0` being midnight. At what point does 8 PM become 19? Why do you insist that [a 24 hour time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) works any other way than it actually does?